# Setting up puppet directory environment in puppet

Tags: module, puppet, init, test-environments

I am learning puppet but I stuck with one problem.
I have a Puppet installation with one Puppet master and one Puppet agent, and I am using open source Puppet.
I to set up a environment named Test. The directory is as follows `/etc/puppet/environments/Test` its having `modules` and `manifests` directories. And `environment.conf` file.

My `environment.conf` contains the following line:

`modulepath = $confdir/environments/production/modules`

I created a module named `sample` inside the `modules` directory of the environment. Described one class called `sample` inside the `init.pp` of the `sample` module's `manifests` directory. The class is used to install a small software.
In the the `manifests` directory of the environment Test I created a file `site.pp` which will implement the class `sample` defined inside the module.

My `puppet.conf` contains this following lines:

`[main]
    logdir=/var/log/puppet
    vardir=/var/lib/puppet
    ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
    rundir=/var/run/puppet
    factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
    prerun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre
    postrun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post
    server=puppet.master`

`[master]
    ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN
    ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY`

But whenever I tried to implement the manifests in the Puppet agent, It is using the default `site.pp` and not using the environments `site.pp`

Can anyone tell me where I am doing the mistake.

Comment: In Puppet `3.x`, you need to specify the `environmentpath` option to make environment directories work. Also, using an absolute path as `modulepath` in an `environment.conf` is self-defeating, consider changing that to `= modules`, or just skipping it as that's the default.

Answer (score 1):

In puppet **agent** configuration (usually /etc/puppet/puppet.conf) set the environment var to Test as follows:

```
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
prerun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre
postrun_command=/etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post
server=puppet.master

[agent]
pluginsync      = true
report          = true
ignoreschedules = true
daemon          = false
ca_server       = server fqdn
certname        = client fqdn (signed in the server)
server          = server fqdn
show_diff       = true
listen          = true
environment     = Test
```